# Open Standard Select Files Modal via lighting web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, related-list, files, fileupload

I have a community page which consist of a `lightning-datatable` filled with `Opportunity` records. As an action of the table I need to add **Add Files** action. Onclick of this action, user should see the standard **Select Files** modal.

[image]

Is this something possible to achieve with the current capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a standard way of doing this. I had raised a case with Salesforce with a similar issue and I ended up using a custom component using lightning-file-upload. I believe you need to recreate a similar modal in LWC. For now I didn't include all the bells and whistle as the standard modal, but I'm working on it for the next project as an enhancement.